# How to I reference date picker created in storyboard and give it default value?

Tags: ios, objective-c, datepicker, storyboard

I created a date picker in storyboard and put in a view controller.

I would like the default date to be provided dynamically from core data.  I think this can be done simply with something like:

```
[datePicker setDate:self.event.date];
```

in viewdidload once I have the name of the datePicker.

However, I don't know how to grab a reference to the date picker created in storyboard from code.

Can anyone suggest right way to do this?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bring up an "assistant editor" (2nd editing pane). Select your view controller scene in the primary editor, and then select the view controller's header in the second editor window. Control-drag from the date picker into the @interface of the view controller to create an outlet. Now use that outlet to refer to the date picker.

Answer (score 0):

You have to link the datepicker on the storyboard to the IBOutlet defined on the .h file of the controller.

[Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_Overview/edit_user_interface.html) you can see an example with images of how you can link it from the story board view and many other usefull tips.